# How to create a safe user sign up

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, registration

So I'm trying to map out a user login and registration page but I am not sure how to make it secure. Is it enough to store the login information in the database? Or should I be incorporating some sort of password hashing?

Comment: yes, you should do as much as you can to secure passwords

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use npm packages like `bcrypt` to implement password hashing. But if you want to implement yourself then go ahead.

Comment: I see. I didn't know npm had packages like that. Thank you! I'll take a good through it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, password encriptation can be used to make it more secure. Another thing you can think about is to avoid return user details from your api, even it they are encripted. Only return which is essential.

You can use JWT (Json Web Token) and expiration policies to make it more secure and improve your application performance and user experience.

For any reference, you can use https://jwt.io/

Also, you can use assigned cookie to make it more secure.

Check it our on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Another way to deal with it is using OAuth and you can find more information on https://oauth.net/2/

Hope all this things can help you with it.

Comment: Thank you for the options, I wasn't sure which directions I could go. I'll check these ones out.

Comment: No problem @Rednirug! Depends on the situation you can use one or another or even all of that options. If you need an example I have some repositories which I'm using JWT and encriptation. https://github.com/tvaccari34